# iOS / Android transparent (invisible) authentication

Tags: android, ios, authentication

I am developing backend for iOS / Android applications and currently I need to implement authentication mechanisms for it.

It's quite pretty easy to implement login/password authentication, social and so on. But not in our case ...

I don't want to enforce user to use such authentications mechanisms and I want to allow him do it later. Instead, I want to automatically create user on the backend side for each new device what launched my iOS/Android app.

It should be transparent process for user, and he must not know about it — I plan just to show notifications with advices to create real account to not to lose the data.

My idea is to create RSA key on mobile device and then exchange its' public part with the backend, then use it as a password.

So the question: `is there any ready/complete solutions which provide such functionality out of the box?`. Or mby such authentication mechanism has a unique name and you know it. Please, advice how to implement it better.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS**
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1395339-seckeygeneratepair?language=objc

**Android**
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyPairGenerator

These are the two operating systems built in libraries however you may be able to find libraries that offer convenience wrappers around these.